# Message addressed to one component delivers to other

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

following is my ejabberd yml configuration

```
-
port: 8888
ip: "::"
module: ejabberd_service
access: all
shaper_rule: fast
ip: "127.0.0.1"
privilege_access:
roster: "both"
message: "outgoing"
presence: "roster"
delegations:
"urn:xmpp:mam:1":
filtering: ["node"]
"http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub":
filtering: []
hosts:
"mycomponent.p-pc":
password: "secret"
"sender.p-pc":
password: "secret"
```

**messages addressed to mycomponent.p-pc are delivered to sender.p-pc**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hosts` variable is a list of *aliases* of a single component, not a different component name